# Raspberry PI for loop to flash LED not working

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I've got a Raspberry PI and am trying to make the LED flash like so:

```
def flash():
    GPIO.output(channel, not GPIO.input(channel))
    sleep(1)
    GPIO.output(channel, not GPIO.input(channel))
```

This works if I call it in my code, it flashes for one second.

If I use this in a loop, to make it flash > 1 time, it does not work.

```
while True:
        flash()
```

It never flashes.  If I call flash 2 times in a row outside the loop, it works.

What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't there be a sleep after turning it off to see a flashing LED? 
Try removing the second `GPIO.output(channel, not GPIO.input(channel))` call and then try using the while loop.

```
def flash():
  GPIO.output(channel, not GPIO.input(channel))
  sleep(1)

while True:
  flash()
```